# Write ntfs file system in el capitan

Tags: macos, ntfs

I have a hard disk which is in NTFS.
I want to make it writable without formatting.

I have gone through some solution for it but its working in previous version not in el captian.

I tried this [link](https://gist.github.com/mrpatiwi/8bca2f20b140150f1cbd)
but when doing this step

```
sudo mv /sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs.original 
sudo ln -s /usr/local/sbin/mount_ntfs /sbin/mount_ntfs
```

its says its not permitted.

Comment: Well did you disable SIP yet?

Comment: sip??? whats it

Comment: SIP = https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It is writeable when you use a ntfs driver: it is not the disk but the OSX that you should "help".
 There are several: the most experienced (in my opinion) are Tuxeira NTFS (opensource) and Paragon NTFS. Lately Tuxeira is the fastest update when the OSX is updated/upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use 3rd party softwares for this job like Paragon NTFS, Tuxeria NTFS.